# Ansible 2.2: Look for a value in a list using with_sequence

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I want to do the following:

```
- lineinfile:
     dest: "file{{ item }}.properties"
     line: "port: {{ port_list[item - 1] }}"
  with_sequence: start=1 end={{ nb_process }}
```

I have the port_list variables which contains the port to be inserted in each property file. I have the following error in return:

```
 unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'int'
```

Any idea ? I have tried also

```
 line: "port: {{ port_list[(item - 1)|int] }}"
```

Without success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
line: "port: {{ port_list[item|int - 1] }}"
```